# Opening MySQLConnection on localhost very slow. Using .Net connector

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connect

I'm trying to learn to use C# with Visual Studio 2015 and the MySqlConnection.Open() method is taking over 15 seconds to establish the connection.

The program I've written simply establishes the connection and displays a message confirming connected or not. No queries, selection or anything else.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue. Could it be my TCP/IP settings? The port? Firewall? I'm not experienced with networking issues and I'm stumped and Google is not helping.

```
        try
        {
            string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            myConn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");
            myConn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Disconnected");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: If you were to run the above code in an empty project would it still take 15 seconds?

Comment: It is an empty project.

Comment: I just tried it as a console application as well. Same thing happened...

Comment: Have you tried resetting SQL server?

Comment: Yeah I've done that. Tempted to do a clean install of MySQL but not sure what thats going to achieve.

Comment: I'd try that next... The code you've shown should not be prone to slow connectivity.

Comment: try turning off your firewall first, and check if it went faster, if it didn't, i guess it's in your port, there's a traffic in the port when you're trying to establish a connection

Comment: I tried disabling the firewall, that made no difference. How can I monitor the port to detect other traffic and find another port that has no other traffic. Wireshark?

Comment: Using MySqlConnector v 1.3.13 for Xamarin extremely slow. It's up to the developer not you.